# Plain Javascript: equivalent of jQuery $.data('key',value)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some functions with jQuery and now I want to make them plain JS.

```js
$('#selector').mouseenter( function( e1 ) {
  var item = $(this);

  clearTimeout(item.data('hoverTimer'));
  var timer = setTimeout( function( e1 ) {
        //do stuff
    }   
  }, 50 );
  item.data('hoverTimer', timer);       
}).mouseleave( function( e2 ) {
  var item = $(this);

  clearTimeout(item.data('hoverTimer'));
  var timer = setTimeout( function( e2 ) {
    //do the other stuff
  }, 300 );
  item.data('hoverTimer', timer);       
});
```

I need to know how to put it in plain JS for setting the timeout data and how to clear the timeout data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using Local SessionStorage in order to access these timer values:

```
var hoverTimer;

$('#selector').mouseenter( function(e) {
    clearTimeout(sessionStorage.getItem('hoverTimer'));
    // Create a new timer
    var timer = setTimeout( function(e) {
        // do stuff
    }, 50);
    // Update the sessionStorage with our new timer
    sessionStorage.setItem('hoverTimer', timer);
}).mouseleave( function(e) {
    clearTimeout(sessionStorage.getItem('hoverTimer'));
    var timer = setTimeout( function(e) {
        // do the other stuff
    }, 300);
    // Update sessionStorage with our new time
    sessionStorage.setItem('hoverTimer', timer);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/om0kvefe/1/)

Comment: I know that, my question is about storing some value over time and use it or clear it on certain events, check my code more careful.

Comment: So you are looking to run a timer on mouseenter and mouseleave. But mouseleave would set the length of time as a dataset value.

Comment: Has nothing to do with dataset, I believe it's about sessionStorage. I am reading now.

Comment: you can use sessionStorage to hold some value temporarily. Shall I edit the code for how to do that?

Comment: Be my guest, you may get a small bounty :)

Comment: Keep in mind that using `sessionStorage` as per the above example, while functional, is not equivalent to the jQuery code in the question. The three major differences are that the timers only stick around for the page session in the original question, whereas in the above example, the timers "stick around" for the entire _browser session_. Secondly, the `hoverTimer` belongs to the element in question, instead of belonging to session storage. Finally, you need to keep in mind that the timer value is opaque, and does not work between page refreshes (and is not guaranteed to be a number).

Comment: @Stephn_R your code is not Plain JS and I already tried that you did here, it's not working.

Comment: Are we saying that you want the event binding to be in plainJS as well?

Comment: @skeggse could you please provide a working example.

Comment: @Stephn_R I already have the code with addEventListener binded, I am getting error because cannot get it from an undefined thing.

Comment: @Danny can you clarify regarding what you are "getting" from a "thing"?

Comment: @skeggse inside the functions the variables become undefined. I just realized PLAIN JS always needs reassigning variables in nested/child functions. I think both your answers are fine, but yours is best.

Comment: Hmm not sure how the functionality of functions (woops) would change in such a way based on the presence or absence of jQuery, but it sounds like you've figured it out.

Comment: I agree with Danny, plus sessionStorage isn't a "fool-proof" approach for this kind of job. You would always be better off storing it in a local variable (just like Danny did)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something that is equivalent to your original code, keep in mind that jQuery as a tool is designed to bridge browser inconsistencies. The following is functional on newer browsers that support `addEventListener`, `document.querySelector`, and `dataset`. Also note that [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and `mouseleave` were originally [proprietary to Internet Explorer](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), and other browsers are only recently adopting the two events. YMMV.

#### Option 1

This works, but I'm not super familiar with the implications of storing the timer as an arbitrary property of the DOM element. This is better than option 2 in that it works for any opaque value `timer` (given that the specification for `setTimeout` is that the return value can be any value, not just serializable values like numbers).

```
var element = document.querySelector('#selector');
element.timer = null;

element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  // you probably want to ensure that element.timer is not null first
  // just replicating the original code
  clearTimeout(element.timer);
  element.timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // do stuff
  }, 50);
});

element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  clearTimeout(element.timer);
  element.timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // do the other stuff
  }, 300);
});
```

#### Option 2

This option assumes that `setTimeout` returns a value which is serializable, which is generally true for browsers (but not true for environments like Node.js).

```
var element = document.querySelector('#selector');
element.dataset.timer = '';

element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  // you probably want to ensure that element.timer is not null first
  // just replicating the original code
  clearTimeout(element.timer);
  element.dataset.timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // do stuff
  }, 50);
});

element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  clearTimeout(element.timer);
  element.dataset.timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // do the other stuff
  }, 300);
});
```

Note that both options assume you don't care about the `element` variable cluttering any containing namespaces. Use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) if that concerns you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been playing with the http://jsfiddle.net/om0kvefe/4 ; (this one is updated) that @Stephn_R provided and it worked, and now with full plain js even, but your code made it clear I had to delete the e1,e <code>function(e1)</code> and this was causing undefined vars inside the setTimeout. So I'm gonna check his answer. I know yours works too.